# Join a Facebook group secretly

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups, permissions

I want to join a Facebook group defined as **Closed group**. The thing is, I don't want any of my friends to know about my membership in this group.

For example, if I post a status in the group, my friends wouldn't be noticed (through their news feed) about it.

Is it possible?

Comment: Since you can never know what Facebook changes in the future the only *truly* secure way is using a separate Facebook account.

Answer (score 6):

If you join a *secret* Facebook group your presence on the group is unknown and posts on the group are only visible to others in the group.

A *closed* group however only limits who can see the posts. Who is a member is public.

Either ask the group to switch to *Secret* or don't join.